# How to make a form with HTML, CSS and JS (without jQuery and bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem. I have two forms. One is done with jQuery and bootstrap and looks fine. I want to make the same form without jQuery and bootstrap, by using vanilla HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Without using the external library. I tried to make that form and it looks much worse than the first one. How should I do so that other forms look the same as the first one only by using HTML, CSS, and JS? And it needs to be responsive.

This is good form: [good form](http://products.dd-webdesign.com/)

This is a bad form: [bad form](https://html-css-seo.000webhostapp.com/feedback/feedback3.html)

p.s.how can I put index.html file and main.css and js file here? Or all code?!

Comment: to share your code, you can just copy and paste into a code snippet or link a fiddle.

Comment: No it's far easier to add CSS/HTML/Javascript - use the 7th icon here on Stack Overflow

Comment: bootstrap is just a file with much classes in it , you can style your form by your self if you know HTML and CSS . <br> for JS handling , you can get the inputs values , validate them on submit . <br>
see this tutorial on w3schools [Input Text value Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) <br>
you can use events , like onsubmit , onchange , onclick , onblur or... to call your function for validatation. <br>
see this tutorial on w3schools for [form validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp)